# how to apply date filter on ancestor query

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I have two entity model Student and attendance such that each attendance entity has associated student parent.

**Attendance model:**

```
@Entity
public class Attendance {

 @Id
 Long id;
 @Index
 Date date;
 @Parent
 @Index
 @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
 Ref<Student> studentRef;

 public Long getId() {
 return id;
 }

 public Date getDate() {
 return date;
 }

 public void setDate(Date date) {
 this.date = date;
 }
 public String getWebsafeKey() {
 return Key.create(studentRef.getKey(), Attendance.class, id).getString();
 }
}
```

**Student model:**

```
@Entity
public class Student {

 @Id
 Long id;
 @Index
 String name;

 String student_id;

 Long mobile_number;
 String email;

 @Index
 @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
 List<Ref<Shift>> shiftRef = new ArrayList<Ref<Shift>>();

 public Long getId() {
 return id;
 }

 public String getStudent_id() {
 return student_id;
 }

 public void setStudent_id(String student_id) {
 this.student_id = student_id;
 }

 public String getName() {
 return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
 this.name = name;
 }

 public Long getMobile_number() {
 return mobile_number;
 }

 public void setMobile_number(Long mobile_number) {
 this.mobile_number = mobile_number;
 }

 public String getEmail() {
 return email;
 }

 public void setEmail(String email) {
 this.email = email;
 }

 public String getWebsafeKey() {
 return Key.create(Student.class, id).getString();
 }
}
```

This how I am inserting an attendance entity into datastore:

```
Key<Student> studentKey = Key.create(student_web_safe_key);
Date date = new Date();
date.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
attendance.setDate(date);
attendance.studentRef = Ref.create(studentKey);
ofy().save().entity(attendance).now();
```

Questions:

1. The above query store the date in datastore in format:**2016-06-15 (18:01:18.845)IST**
   But when I retrieve the same entity without specifying its parent then its gives me date as: **"date ": "2016-06-15T12:31:18.845Z"**. please explain this?
2. I am able to store attendance corresponds to each student and also able to retrieve all the attendance of a student.
   but how can retrieve attendance of student on specified date or range of dates?
   I tried blow query:
   **Query query = ofy().load().type(Attendance.class).ancestor(studentKey).filter("date =",date);**

but it gives me following exception:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 

503 Service Unavailable
    {
      "code": 503,
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "global",
          "message": "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found. recommended index is:\n- kind: Attendance\n  ancestor: yes\n  properties:\n  - name: date\n\nThe suggested index for this query is:\n    <datastore-index kind=\"Attendance\" ancestor=\"true\" source=\"manual\">\n        <property name=\"date\" direction=\"asc\"/>\n    </datastore-index>\n\n",
          "reason": "backendError"
        }
      ],
      "message": "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found. recommended index is:\n- kind: Attendance\n  ancestor: yes\n  properties:\n  - name: date\n\nThe suggested index for this query is:\n    <datastore-index kind=\"Attendance\" ancestor=\"true\" source=\"manual\">\n        <property name=\"date\" direction=\"asc\"/>\n    </datastore-index>\n\n"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering Question 1:**

Appengine uses UTC timestamps. Therefor your timestamp is converted from your time zone to UTC. It is still the same date and time though. During output you need to consider that the timestamp may contain the timezone and format / calculate the local time accordingly.

**Answering Question 2:**

You have all the information you need in your error. If you add

```
<datastore-index kind="Attendance" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="date" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

to your [datastore-indexes.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig) your query should work. 
If the file doesn't exist yet, create it under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml`, next to your *web.xml* and *appengine-web.xml* files.
You can find an [example on this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig).

As for why: The answer with this error is always: Because datastore requires a composite index for this query.

Comment: thanks for comment @konqi...I search alot but i didn't find datastore-indexes.xml file my android studio. can you please tell me where this file located in android studio?

Comment: `datastore-indexes.xml` is actually a link. Click it and you will find that the file should go in the WEB-INF folder, the same place where your web.xml and appengine-web.xml are.

Comment: where this link located in android studio?

Comment: I meant the link in my answer, the URL is: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig

Comment: @Baqir see my answer I posted some code on what you need to do with Android Studio + Cloud Endpoints

Comment: can you please tell me how to remove created composite-index from datastore?

Comment: @Baqir the process is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Datastore_Deleting_unused_indexes). If that doesn't help, please open another question if it hasn't been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add to konqi's answer based on comments:

If you are using Cloud Endpoints with Android Studio you must first switch to "project" view in your navigation panel, then navigate to your "backend" folder then src->main->webapp->WEB-INF and then in that folder you must manually create a datastore-indexes.xml file. Here is what yours would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
    <!-- NOTE: Not necessary to create composite indexes here for single property indices b.c. they are build in.-->

    <!-- If you do not specify direction, default is: direction="asc" -->

    <datastore-index kind="Attendance" ancestor="true" source="manual">
        <property name="date" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>

</datastore-indexes>
```

Comment: I can't decide whether to flag this as "not an answer" since it doesn't answer the question on its own. It should be comment and/or improved to be standalone and/or you're welcome to edit my answer.

Comment: @konqi I believe if an "answer" helps people who are confused (both the OP and future readers) then it should stand. This area of using Cloud Endpoints +  Google App Engine is poorly documented and there is a lot of confusion for beginners. Feel free to add it to your answer and I will delete mine tho lol =) I don't mind

Comment: Uhm, the problem has nothing to do with Cloud Endpoints and indexes are actually one of the better documented features. Try to find out how to implement a custom authenticator in Cloud Endpoints, that would be poorly documented. The main issue i have with your answer is that it answers something that wasn't asked in the question. The op doesn't ask for Android Studio. That question arises from the comments to my answer, so to understand your question one has to read the comments first. When I delete my answer yours makes no sense. You think that makes things less confusing? Fine with me.

Comment: @konqi So the solution is for the OP to specify that he is using android studio (which he is), for me to delete my question and append my answer to yours. I am totally fine doing that but I am willing to bet that me, you and the OP are too lazy to do that so future comers to this page will have to do a little scavenger hunting =P (Ironically we are less lazy to just comment back and forth lol)

Comment: *shrug* i added the essence of your answer into mine which was basically just the full path. I don't do IDE instructions, i like to keep my answers generic so they work for everybody. If someone is not (even) capable of handleing the chosen development environment i am unwilling to help.

Comment: @MicroR ...your answer is based on my comments as konqi said...actually its my fault as I didn't mentioned about IDE in my question and it make no sense to edit question.But your answer helped me in finding(creating) datastore-index.html so vote up for you.