# Multiple indexes GAE objectify

Tags: android, google-app-engine, indexing, entity, objectify

I've the following Entity on my Android Project :

```
@Entity
public class Journey {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Ref<User> driver;
    @Index private Ref<Event> event;
    private Long nbPlaces;
    @Index private String departureTime;
    private String destination;
    @Index private String departureDate;
}
```

And the following query on my Endpoint :

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "listJourneyByEvent",
        path = "journeyByEvent",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
public CollectionResponse<Journey> listJourneyByEvent(@Named("idEvent") Long idEvent, @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursor, @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {
    limit = limit == null ? DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT : limit;
    Key<Event> key = Key.create(Event.class, idEvent);

    Query<Journey> query = ofy().load().type(Journey.class).filter("event", key).order("departureDate").limit(limit);
    if (cursor != null) {
        query = query.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursor));
    }
    QueryResultIterator<Journey> queryIterator = query.iterator();
    List<Journey> journeyList = new ArrayList<Journey>(limit);
    while (queryIterator.hasNext()) {
        journeyList.add(queryIterator.next());
    }
    return CollectionResponse.<Journey>builder().setItems(journeyList).setNextPageToken(queryIterator.getCursor().toWebSafeString()).build();
}
```

But when I execute the method I receive the following error :

```
E/ch.hevs.co_voituragefiesta.async.AsyncJourneyList: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
                                                                                                               {
                                                                                                                 "code": 503,
                                                                                                                 "errors": [
                                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                                     "domain": "global",
                                                                                                                     "message": "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found. recommended index is:\n- kind: Journey\n  properties:\n  - name: event\n  - name: departureDate\n\nThe suggested index for this query is:\n    <datastore-index kind=\"Journey\" ancestor=\"false\" source=\"manual\">\n        <property name=\"event\" direction=\"asc\"/>\n        <property name=\"departureDate\" direction=\"asc\"/>\n    </datastore-index>\n\n",
                                                                                                                     "reason": "backendError"
                                                                                                                   }
                                                                                                                 ],
                                                                                                                 "message": "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found. recommended index is:\n- kind: Journey\n  properties:\n  - name: event\n  - name: departureDate\n\nThe suggested index for this query is:\n    <datastore-index kind=\"Journey\" ancestor=\"false\" source=\"manual\">\n        <property name=\"event\" direction=\"asc\"/>\n        <property name=\"departureDate\" direction=\"asc\"/>\n    </datastore-index>\n\n"
                                                                                                               }
```

I've read that the GAE take some time to generate the Indexes but I think that isn't the problem.

I also read that we can't have multiple indexes in an Entity.. Is that true ?

Thanks

Comment: this may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852404/how-to-apply-date-filter-on-ancestor-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Datastore builds automatic indexes for queries of the following forms:
>   ... Queries with no filters and only one sort order on a property, either ascending or descending ..

[documentation source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Index_configuration)

You are using query with filter and sort, so you have to specify index manually. Google gives you index definition in exception:

```
<datastore-index kind="Journey" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="event" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="departureDate" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

Add this index in your datastore-indexes.xml file, deploy and wait for index to build (check datastore indexes status in console)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tijkijiki. I don't find the file datastore-indexes.xml. Maybe I've to create it manually ? Regards